# Take user input to create a `for` loop in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application in Android that will prompt the user to enter a height and width, then create a grid to the dimensions the user entered.
I have created an activity where I have dragged inputs for the user to enter a number, I was wondering how do I use these values in another class. so how to use the user input in a view is what I'm asking I guess

Comment: Post your code with proper description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want to use the user input in many classes, so you could save these values for width and height in `SharedPreferences` and use them from all of the classes of your app like this for example:

```
String width = widthtextView.getText().toString();
String height = heightTextView.getText().toString();
...
//save the values in sharedPrefferences - the name could be what you want
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("width", width);
editor.putInt("height", height);
editor.commit();
```

And then you could get them back like this for example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsName", MODE_PRIVATE); 
int width = prefs.getInt("width", 0); //0 is the default value
int height = prefs.getInt("height", 0); //0 is the default value
```

Hopefully this helps you :)